# Undo a "Reject" on a suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I saw that a question had a pending edit, but the edit made no improvement whatsoever.

So I clicked "Reject", at the same time I realised that the question did actually need some editing. I should have clicked "Reject and Edit"!

But by now there's nothing I can do to edit the question, other than wait for the suggested edit to be fully rejected (or even approved by the robo-reviewers).
Or is there?

Edit: Although there are questions very similar to this one, my request is more straightforward I believe: allow people to retract their "reject" or "approve" votes, in the same way retracting "close" votes works.

Comment: If you retract your vote, you still have to wait for the review to complete. Unless you're suggesting being able to re-cast it, which isn't allowed with close votes.